# WFS layer imported via QGIS, features are rotated/flipped, how can I correct this?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, wfs, georeferencing

I have made a connection [to this WFS layer](https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/sssi-impact-risk-zones-england/wfs) through the QGIS data source manager:

[image: QGIS Data source manager]

The layer takes a very long time to load, but when it does it appears flipped and rotated:

[image: WFS SSSI Layer flipped/rotated incorrectly]

I think this has something to do with coordinate reversal, maybe the order in which QGIS is expecting the X and Y fields?

Can anyone suggest a way for me to correct this for a WFS layer? I'm fairly comfortable with the PyQGIS API.

Comment: So what kind of information/parameters/URL etc. exactly did you enter?

Comment: Check the flip axis order box on the connection page, or use a different version of wfs standard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ian Turton commented with the answer (thank you). I also found it in [this previous question.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400904/wfs-not-displaying-in-right-orientation)

I edited the WFS connection and checked the "Invert axis orientation" box. It should be noted that this caused the layer to flag for "repair data source" until I saved the project, closed and re-opened it. I've also notified the data provider that it is returning with incorrect axis order for this CRS (OSGB36 / British National Grid).

[image: Check invert axis orientation box]